# Ensure adjacent column values using pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe:

```
index    col1    col2     col3
    0       X       A      123
    1       X       A      456
    2       X       B      654
    3       X       B      321
    4       X       A      111
```

I'm trying to use `pivot_table` to get this df into the following format:

```
index       A       B
    0     123     654  
    1     456     321 
    2     111     NaN
```

I'm trying to use... `pivot_table(index=df.index, columns=['col2'], values='col3')`, however this just ends up in the following state:

```
index       A       B
    0     123     NaN  
    1     456     NaN 
    2     111     NaN
    3     NaN     654 
    4     NaN     321
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still using `pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=df.groupby('col2').cumcount(),columns='col2',values='col3')
Out[163]: 
col2      A      B
0     123.0  654.0
1     456.0  321.0
2     111.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `pivot_table` is correct.

To combine records (in the pivoted dataframe), which you are asking about, you need first use `pivot_table` and then simply drop the NaNs from the pivoted dataframe using `apply`, as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119544/4057186):

```
# Perform spreadsheet-style pivot table
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns=['col2'], values='col3')
print df2

# Drop NaNs to shift rows up and combine records
df1 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print (df1)
```

The output is:

```
# df2
col2      A      B
0     123.0    NaN
1     456.0    NaN
2       NaN  654.0
3       NaN  321.0
4     111.0    NaN

# df1
col2      A      B
0     123.0  654.0
1     456.0  321.0
2     111.0    NaN
```