# pandas groupby ffill bfill needs intermediate groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to paper over missing data in a dataframe by grouping on one column and then flood-filling (bfill().ffill()) subsets of columns inside the groups.

I was previously using

```
def ffbf(x):
   return x.ffill().bfill()

df[some_cols] = df.groupby(group_key)[some_cols].transform(ffbf)
```

but transform becomes *unbelievably* slow even on relatively small dataframes (already several seconds for only 3000x20), so I wanted to see if I could apply ffill and bfill directly to the groups since they're supposed to be cythonized now.

Am I correct in thinking that I need to invoke groupby again in between ffill and bfill because neither method preserves the groupings?

Right now I have

```
df[some_cols] = df[some_cols].groupby(group_key).ffill().groupby(group_key).bfill()
```

and I *think* that it's doing what I want, and it's waaaaaaayyy faster than using transform, but I'm not experienced enough with pandas to be certain, so I figured I'd ask.

[edit] It looks like this change is jumbling my data. Why?

Comment: You should have asked after spending enough time on it, because that looks fine as is.

Comment: It's not fine at all. I see now that the data has been getting jumbled up by this change, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I my opinion here is necessary another `groupby` with `bfill` for avoid replace `NaN`s for only `NaN`s group from another one.

For performance is used this code:

```
In [205]: %timeit df1[some_cols] = df1.groupby(group_key)[some_cols].transform(ffbf)
443 ms ± 7.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [206]: %timeit df[[group_key] + some_cols] = df[[group_key] + some_cols].groupby(group_key).ffill().groupby(group_key).bfill()
5.69 ms ± 31.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
np.random.seed(785)

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'A':np.random.choice([1,2,np.nan], size=N),
                   'B':np.random.choice([1,4,np.nan], size=N),
                   'C':np.random.choice([7,0,np.nan], size=N),
                   'D':np.random.choice([7,0,8], size=N)})

df = df.sort_values('key')
print (df)

def ffbf(x):
   return x.ffill().bfill()

group_key = 'key'
some_cols = ['A','B','C']
df1 = df.copy()
df1[some_cols] = df1.groupby(group_key)[some_cols].transform(ffbf)

#a bit chamgef solution for working in pandas 0.23.1
df[[group_key] + some_cols] = df[[group_key] + some_cols].groupby(group_key).ffill().groupby(group_key).bfill()

print (df.equals(df1))
True
```

EDIT: In next pandas versions (test pandas 1.1.1) is possible use:

```
df[[group_key] + some_cols] = df[[group_key] + some_cols].groupby(df[group_key]).ffill().groupby(df[group_key]).bfill()
```

Comment: how to Remove NaN from the cell array without dropping the entire row, in a single line for a dataframe?

Comment: @pyd - You can only shift all values like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43119503/2901002), because need always same DataFrame structure. (only change axis=1) to `apply`. last is possible remove only NaNs rows by `df = df.dropna(how='all')`

Comment: @jezrael Do you know why using `df[[group_key] + some_cols]` in your answer gives a different result than `df[some_cols + [group_key]]`? It looks like the order matters, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @ackermanj In my opinion it is awfull bug, universal solution should be with join - `df = df.drop(some_cols + [group_key], axis=1).join(df[some_cols + [group_key]].groupby(group_key).ffill().groupby(group_key).bfill()).reindex(columns=df.columns)`

Comment: This no longer works, due to this regression in functionality: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#dataframe-groupby-ffill-bfill-no-longer-return-group-labels

Comment: @Isaac - need `df[[group_key] + some_cols] = df[[group_key] + some_cols].groupby(df[group_key]).ffill().groupby(df[group_key]).bfill()`

Answer (score 1):

As @Isaac noted, the accepted answer no longer works. @jezrael's modification (in the comments of accepted answer) fails if there is more than one grouping variable. Here's an updated modification of @jezrael's answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
print(pd.__version__)

np.random.seed(785)

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':np.random.randint(30, size=N),
                   'key2':np.random.randint(30, size=N),
                   'A':np.random.choice([1,2,np.nan], size=N),
                   'B':np.random.choice([1,4,np.nan], size=N),
                   'C':np.random.choice([7,0,np.nan], size=N),
                   'D':np.random.choice([7,0,8], size=N)})

df = df.sort_values(['key1', 'key2'])

def ffbf(x):
   return x.ffill().bfill()

group_keys = ['key1', 'key2']
some_cols = ['A','B','C']
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

# slow method
df1[some_cols] = df1.groupby(group_keys)[some_cols].transform(ffbf)

# fast method
gidx = df2.groupby(group_keys, sort=False).ngroup()
df2 = df2.groupby(gidx).ffill().groupby(gidx).bfill()

print (df2.equals(df1))

import timeit
slow = """dfn = df.groupby(group_keys)[some_cols].transform(ffbf)"""
print(timeit.timeit(slow, globals=globals(), number=20))

fast = """gidx = df.groupby(group_keys, sort=False).ngroup()
dfn = df.groupby(gidx).ffill().groupby(gidx).bfill()"""
print(timeit.timeit(fast, globals=globals(), number=20))
```

Output:

```
3.10.13
2.0.3
True
4.181147900002543
0.07793619995936751
```