# How to resize dataframe by dropping NaN in individual cells?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have a df that looks like this:

```
column1   column2    column3   column4
1            2       nan          4
1            2        3           nan
1            2       nan          nan
1            2       nan          nan
```

How do I reshape the dataframe, for every cell with NaN drop it, and if the column has the same value only take one instance of it?

New df should look like this;

```
column1   column2    column3   column4
1            2        3          4
```

I have roughly 500 columns with spotty data like this.

Edit:

I used this line of code to move the values with the spotty data into one row.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

new df looks like this:

```
column1   column2    column3   column4
1            2        3            4
1            2       nan          nan
1            2       nan          nan
1            2       nan          nan
```

Then I drop the duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

df looks like this now:

```
 column1   column2    column3   column4
    1            2        3            4
    1            2       nan          nan
```

Not sure why the Nan are not dropping after this point with but the rows are dropping:

```
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward fill missing values by `ffill`, remove `NaN`s rows and remove duplicates:

```
df = df.ffill().dropna().drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   column1  column2  column3  column4
1        1        2      3.0      4.0
```

Or if need first non missing values per groups specified by some column(s):

```
df = df.groupby(['column1','column2'], as_index=False).first()
print (df)

   column1  column2  column3  column4
0        1        2      3.0      4.0
```

Comment: `df = df.ffill().dropna().drop_duplicates()` is dropping all my rows. I am being left with only columns

Comment: @RustyShackleford - It seems in data is at least one only NaNs columns, so try remove this columns by `df.dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna().ffill().drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: But hard to answer without [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I guess create it is complicated :(

Comment: @jezrael The question is dupe of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119503/how-to-remove-blanks-nas-from-dataframe-and-shift-the-values-up)

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Not sure, if `500` columns is possible use it.

Comment: @RustyShackleford - reason is `nan` are strings, try `df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)` in first step