# How to iterate over DataFrame columns and drop NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this example DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, np.NaN], 'col2': [3, np.NaN, 4], 'col3': [np.NaN, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

and want to drop NaN values in that way to get the resulting dataFrame in this shape

[image]

I tried to iterate over columns and use dropna() function on each column but that didn't work:

```
for i in columns:
    df3[i].dropna()
```

Next when I tried :

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['col1', 'col2','col3'])
```

I ended up with df with all rows dropped:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line using 'dropna' of pandas. No need to iterate. Already asked here: [How to remove blanks/NA's from dataframe and shift the values up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119503/how-to-remove-blanks-nas-from-dataframe-and-shift-the-values-up)

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate.
You can use the `dropna` command:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: Applying this to his example and adding 'col3' will drop all rows.

Comment: Yes, this solution dropped all rows when I added the 'col3'