# move column above and delete rows in pandas python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a data frame df like this

```
A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
a.1      b.1     
                  
                  c.1      d.1 
                  c.2      d.2           e.1      f.1 
                                                      

                                                     g.1       h.1
```

Create the sample DataFrame

```
from io import StringIO

s = """A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
a.1,b.1,,,,,,
,,c.1,d.1,,,,
,,c.2,d.2,e.1,f.1,,
,,,,,,g.1,h.1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

I want to remove these extra spaces and I want dataframe to start from the top row. Can anyone help.

my desired results would be

```
A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
a.1      b.1      c.1      d.1      e.1      f.1      g.1       h.1
                  c.2      d.2
```

Comment: Use the first solution from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119503/how-to-remove-blanks-nas-from-dataframe-and-shift-the-values-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift back each column by the number of preceding missing values which is found with `first_valid_index`:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.shift(-s.first_valid_index()))
```

to get

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  d.1  e.1  f.1  g.1  h.1
1  NaN  NaN  c.2  d.2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

To drop the rows full of `NaN`s and fill the rest with empty string:

```
out = (df.apply(lambda s: s.shift(-s.first_valid_index()))
         .dropna(how="all")
         .fillna(""))
```

to get

```
>>> out

     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  d.1  e.1  f.1  g.1  h.1
1            c.2  d.2
```

---

note: this assumes your index is `0..N-1`; so if it's not, you can store it beforehand and then restore back:

```
index = df.index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = (df.apply(lambda s: s.shift(-s.first_valid_index()))
        .dropna(how="all")
        .fillna(""))
df.index = index[:len(df)]
```

---

To make the pulling up specific to some columns:

```
def pull_up(s):
    # this will be a column number; `s.name` is the column name
    col_index = df.columns.get_indexer([s.name])

   # for example: if `col_index` is either 7 or 8, pull by 4
   if col_index in (7, 8):
       return s.shift(-4)
   else:
       # otherwise, pull as much
       return s.shift(-s.first_valid_index())

# applying
df.apply(pull_up)
```

Comment: umm, sorry I missed to mention that this data is example data and in real data index for different columns is different.  Basically, in column 3,4 I need to shift 1 tab up...5,6 will need 2 tabs up....7,8 needs to be pulled 3 tabs up and column 9,10 will need to be shifted 4 tabs

Comment: @sdave Yes in that case you can use the last snippet with `reset_index`; can you please try that?

Comment: yes, I will do it now, my question is instead of df (the whole dataframe) i can simply use df['c'] as well right to work only on the specefic columns?

Comment: @sdave Sure, it should be working that way.

Comment: it works flawlessly where the first_valid_index is column 0 or where we have first non-NaN value. 
```df.iloc[:, 6:8]=df.iloc[:, 6:8].apply(lambda s: s.shift(-s.first_valid_index()))```
but for column 7 and 8 , I have multiple NaN values untill row 50 but I want to pull it only 4 rows up. Basically the column should begin with NaN values but the first 4 rows should be removed and data should be pulled above. Is there any way I can define what (row column combination) should be the first valid index?

Comment: @sdave I edited the answer as far as I understood, hope it helps.

Comment: It worked like a charm, now lastly i have complely empty rows in dataframe , I want to delete them only when all the coumns in the row are empty. dropna is not helping

Comment: @sdave `dropna` has parameter `how` so if you say `df.dropna(how="all")`, it will drop a row only if *all* the columns for that row are empty.

Comment: can you have a look at this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917573/replace-nan-with-sign-only-in-specefic-condition-python-pandas

Comment: can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68020714/how-to-remove-extra-while-reading-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @sdave I saw that but don't know the answer, I hope someone else does.

Comment: Thanks, no problem :)