# replace NaN with '-' sign only in specefic condition ,Python-Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a dataframe

```
 L1      D1     L2      D2         L3
 1.0    ABC     1.1     4.1        NaN
 NaN    NaN     1.7     NaN        NaN
 NaN    4.1     NaN     NaN        NaN
 NaN    1.8     3.2     PQR        NaN
 NaN    NaN     1.6     NaN        NaN
```

I want to replace all the NaN with '-' (only when the value in any column is last value in that row)

so basically my desired output will be

```
 L1      D1      L2      D2         L3
 1.0    ABC     1.1     4.1        -
 NaN    NaN     1.7     -          -
 NaN    4.1      -      -          -
 NaN    1.8     3.2     PQR        -
 NaN    NaN     1.6     -          -
```

Can someone help, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
minus_mask = df.loc[:, ::-1].notna().cumsum(axis=1).eq(0)
out = df.mask(minus_mask, "-")
```

where we first flip the `df` over the columns, look where it is not `NaN` and take the cumulative sum. If the cumulative sum equals 0, those places are where we should put `"-"` so we use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method to put minus signs there,

to get

```
>>> out

    L1   D1   L2   D2 L3
0  1.0  ABC  1.1  4.1  -
1  NaN  NaN  1.7    -  -
2  NaN  4.1    -    -  -
3  NaN  1.8  3.2  PQR  -
4  NaN  NaN  1.6    -  -
```

Comment: as I have non numeric values as well we get this error ```TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value```

Comment: @sdave I see, then we can use `pd.DataFrame.mask` method, edited the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: worked like charm, Thank you so much. I would like to connect/follow you on linkedIn if its okay :)

Comment: @sdave glad to be of help! but i don't use that website `:)`

Comment: I have another request for you ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921612/create-id-column-in-dataframe-based-on-other-column-values-pandas-python