# How do I transform a non-CSV text file into a CSV using Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have a text file that looks like this:

> Id Number: 12345678 
> Location: 1234561791234567090-8.9 
> Street: 999 Street AVE
> Buyer: john doe
> Id Number: 12345688 
> Location: 3582561791254567090-8.9 
> Street: 123 Street AVE
> Buyer: Jane doe @ buyer % LLC
> Id Number: 12345689 
> Location: 8542561791254567090-8.9 
> Street: 854 Street AVE
> Buyer: Jake and Bob: Owner%LLC: Inc

I'd like the file to look like this:

| Id Number | Location | Street | Buyer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 1234561791234567090-8.9 | 999 Street AVE | john doe |
| 12345688 | 3582561791254567090-8.9 | 123 Street AVE | Jane doe @ buyer % LLC |
| 12345689 | 8542561791254567090-8.9 | 854 Street AVE | Jake and Bob: Owner%LLC: Inc |

I have tried the following:

```
# 1 Read text file and ignore bad lines (lines with extra colons thus reading as extra fields).
tr = pd.read_csv('C:\\File Path\\test.txt', sep=':', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)

# 2 Convert into a dataframe/pivot table.
ndf = pd.DataFrame(tr.pivot(index=None, columns=0, values=1))

# 3 Clean up the pivot table to remove NaNs and reset the index (line by line).

nf2 = ndf.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Here is where got the last line (#3): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62481057/10448224

When I do the above and export to CSV the headers are arranged like the following:

| (index) | Street | Buyer | Id Number | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The data is filled in nicely but at some point the Buyer field becomes inaccurate *but* the rest of the fields *are accurate* through the entire DF.

### My guesses:

When I run #1 part of my script I get the following errors 507 times:

```
b'Skipping line 500: expected 2 fields, saw 3\nSkipping line 728: expected 2 fields, saw 3\
```

At the tail end of the new DF I am missing exactly 507 entries for the Byer field. So I think when I drop my bad lines, the field is pushing my data up.

### Pain Points:

The Buyer field will sometimes have extra colons and other odd characters. So when I try to use a colon as a delimiter I run into problems.

I am new to Python and I am very new to using functions. I primarily use Pandas to manipulate data at a somewhat basic level. So in the words of the great Michael Scott: "Explain it to me like I'm five." Many many thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: You should manually split the lines at the first colon with:  `key,value = inputline.split(":",1)`  save them in a dictionary and every you hit the `"Id Number"` (or end of file) append the collected dictionary into your list and start a new dictionary.  You can figure out how to convert that dictionary into a dataframe easily enough.

Comment: @RufusVS could you clarify this part: `key,value = inputline`. Sorry, I'm new to python. I know generally what a dictionary is but don't have a lot of experience using them in this way.

Comment: You will need to provide some example data to show the pain problems in order to get a complete answer.

Comment: @SupaDupa The key point is the split function with the 1 argument, it splits the line into two parts at the `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant by reading in and using split.  Very similar to other answers. Untested and I don't recall if inputline include eol, so I stripped it too.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    data = []  # holds database
    record = {} # holds built up record
    for inputline in f:
        key,value = inputline.strip().split(':',1)
        if key == "Id Number": # new record starting
            if len(record):
                data.append(record) # write previous record
                record = {}
        record.update({key:value})
if len(record):
    data.append(record) # out final record
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Wow. This is really close! Get this error message: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "filepath\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) File "<ipython-input-14-cf4eb6cb7fca>", line 5, in <module>key,value = inputline.strip().split(':',1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` Tried it on a smaller subset of dataset and it worked. However when I try on the larger dataset I get the above error.

Comment: Best guess there was no ':' in the string: `'Id Number'.split(":")  ['Id Number']`. So there was no item in the list to unpack into `value` portion of `key,value`. That is why I asked for an example of the data. In any case you will need to add code to do data clean up to make things work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example that demonstrates the basics:

```
cat split_test.txt 

Id Number: 12345678
Location: 1234561791234567090-8.9
Street: 999 Street AVE
Buyer: john doe
Id Number: 12345688
Location: 3582561791254567090-8.9
Street: 123 Street AVE
Buyer: Jane doe @ buyer % LLC
Id Number: 12345689
Location: 8542561791254567090-8.9
Street: 854 Street AVE
Buyer: Jake and Bob: Owner%LLC: Inc

import csv 

with open("split_test.txt", "r") as f:
    id_val = "Id Number"
    list_var = []
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.strip().split(':')
        print(split_line)
        if split_line[0] == id_val:
            d = {}
            d[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
            list_var.append(d)
        else:
            d.update({split_line[0]: split_line[1]})

list_var

[{'Id Number': ' 12345689',
  'Location': ' 8542561791254567090-8.9',
  'Street': ' 854 Street AVE',
  'Buyer': ' Jake and Bob'},
 {'Id Number': ' 12345678',
  'Location': ' 1234561791234567090-8.9',
  'Street': ' 999 Street AVE',
  'Buyer': ' john doe'},
 {'Id Number': ' 12345688',
  'Location': ' 3582561791254567090-8.9',
  'Street': ' 123 Street AVE',
  'Buyer': ' Jane doe @ buyer % LLC'}]

with open("split_ex.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    field_names = list_var[0].keys()
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in list_var:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try reading the file line by line, splitting the key-value pairs into a list of `dict`s to look something like:

```py
data = [
  {
     "Id Number": 12345678,
     "Location": 1234561791234567090-8.9,
     ...
  },
  {
     "Id Number": ...
  }
]

# easy to create the dataframe from here
your_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: "I would try reading the file line by line, splitting the key-value pairs into a list..." How would I do this? Someone else mentioned splitting using the key-value pairs, but again I am new to python. Thank you.