# Python: remove empty rows and cells show two column data aligns

Tags: python, pandas

I dont understand why empty cells and rows of the attached image are not removed with the following code. [output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ds5W.jpg) I want "Speaker 1 Text" column to align with "Speaker 2 Text" column

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath('/Users/daneweickert/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-weickertdane99@gmail.com/My Drive/Business/gpt3/audio/MMA/sean_omalley/interviews/interview_transcript/tester.csv')

if os.path.isfile(path):
    print("File exist")
else:
    print("File does not exist")


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path)

# Create empty columns called "Speaker 1 Text" and "Speaker 2 Text"
df["Speaker 1 Text"] = ""
df["Speaker 2 Text"] = ""

# Iterate through each row of the data
for i in range(len(df)):
    # Check if the current row contains the string "SPEAKER 1"
    if "SPEAKER 1" in df.iloc[i][0]:
        # If it does, check if the next row is empty
        while pd.isna(df.iloc[i+1][0]):
            i+=1
        # If the next row is not empty, copy the text from the row after that to the "Speaker 1 Text" column
        df.at[i+1, "Speaker 1 Text"] = df.iloc[i+1][0]
    # Check if the current row contains the string "SPEAKER 2"
    elif "SPEAKER 2" in df.iloc[i][0]:
        # If it does, check if the next row is empty
        while pd.isna(df.iloc[i+1][0]):
            i+=1
        # If the next row is not empty, copy the text from the row after that to the "Speaker 2 Text" column
        df.at[i+1, "Speaker 2 Text"] = df.iloc[i+1][0]
        


# Remove the first column
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[0])

# Remove rows with missing values in either column
df.dropna(subset=["Speaker 1 Text", "Speaker 2 Text"], thresh=1, axis=0, inplace=True)

# Save the modified data to a new CSV file
destination = os.path.join('/Users/daneweickert/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-weickertdane99@gmail.com/My Drive/Business/gpt3/test')
df.to_csv(os.path.join(destination, "modified_data.csv"),index=False)
```

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that replicates your problem, and please [do not post images of data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now it's not clear how your input looks like, which makes it hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Dropna is usually meant to erase the whole row if there is an na value (if how="any"). If how="all" it will drop the whole row if all values are na

The answer to this question does what you are looking for [How to remove blanks/NA's from dataframe and shift the values up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119503/how-to-remove-blanks-nas-from-dataframe-and-shift-the-values-up)